# How to make filter search case insensitive?

Tags: jquery

Here is the JS script:

```
this.searchUsers = function(searchUsername) {
    if (searchUsername==='') return;
    var temp = ("[data-username*='"+searchUsername + "']";
    $("div .contactListItem").not(temp).hide();     
};
```

Works fine, except that it is case sensitive on searchUsername. 
How to make it run case insensitive ?
(without changin the data-username value)

Comment: use `searchUsername.toLowerCase()`..

Comment: Try to use the .toLowerCase() function to make them both lowercase.

Comment: The issue is the above will only amend the `searchUsername`, not the attribute itself, so they still wouldn't match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've seen the attribute selector is case sensitive. To amend this behaviour you could use `filter()`:

```
this.searchUsers = function(searchUsername) {
    if (searchUsername === '') 
        return;

    var temp = $("[data-username]").filter(function() {
        return $(this).data('username').toLowerCase().indexOf(searchUsername.toLowercase()) != -1;
    });
    $("div .contactListItem").not(temp).hide();     
};
```

Comment: Problem is: it only filter the EXACT username. My original was matching ANY part thanks to the asterisk : var temp = ("[data-username*='"+searchUsername + "']";

Comment: You're right, my mistake. I've updated the answer for you

Answer (score 0):

First convert javascript string to in lowercase and then compare it..

The toLowerCase() method returns the calling string value converted to lowercase.

for more details check https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase

Comment: But the issue is that the attribute itself may not be lowercase, so you would comparing `Foo` to `foo` and still not getting any match.